# Python - How to send PySerial results to FileMaker Pro 9

Tags: python, macos, filemaker

I currently have a python script set up, using PySerial, that reads incoming weight data from a Mettler-Toledo scale. Everything is working just as I want it to with regards to reading it, but I need to get the result into FileMaker Pro 9. I'm not familiar with FileMaker, but could this be done by invoking the Python script from an AppleScript, or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SerialPort X](http://alteredhorizons.capnix.com/MacSoft.html), it's a free Scripting Extension, so you can work with serial port from AppleScript ([here's an example](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4109589?start=0&tstart=0)).

Answer (score 0):

Applescript should be fine for this, since it's likely running on the client already.